# SQL Query to convert TIMESTAMP to String while selecting the columns

Tags: sql, db2

I am using DB2 database. I have a table and it has two columns as below:

Table name is `sample`:
Below are the columns:

```
CRDATTIM TIMESTAMP NOT NULL , 

RECORDCD CHAR(1) CCSID 37 NOT NULL;
```

The above table has the below values:

```
   CRDATTIM                                   RECORDCD 

2014-08-08 12:12:39.621060                  O   
2014-08-27 07:01:46.814080                  T   
2014-08-27 06:41:47.404080                  T   
2014-08-27 07:14:47.871080                  T   
2014-08-28 02:23:50.390080                  T   
2014-08-28 06:27:58.298080                  T   
2014-09-02 08:57:37.607080                  T
```

Now I want to select all the columns of the table `sample`(select * from sample)by converting the values under `CRDATTIM` column to string, not as `TIMESTAMP`.

For example the value under the column `CRDATTIM` `2014-08-08 12:12:39.621060` should be returned as `2014-08-08-12.12.39.621060`.

Similarly

2014-08-27 07:01:46.814080  should be returned as 2014-08-27-07.01.46.814080

and so on

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: Try nested functions in the SQL for `CRDATTIM` field. Using `TO_CHAR` function to get the timestamp as a string and then apply `REPLACE` function to replace the `space` in the string with a `hyphen`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The above comment is very useful

Comment: Not sure who down voted the question. I don't see any valid reason behind this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aniket V's suggestion helped me in figuring out the solution.

> Try nested functions in the SQL for CRDATTIM field. Using TO_CHAR function to get the timestamp as a string and then apply REPLACE function to replace the space in the string with a hyphen

The below query worked for me to convert Timestamp to specified string format.

```
select  TO_CHAR(CRDATTIM,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.FF6') as CRDATTIM ,recordcd from sample  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer may depend on your DB2-version and operating-system platform for the DB2-server, but try this:

```
select timestamp_format(crdattim,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.NNNNNN'),recordcd from sample
```

You can also try to_char() instead of timestamp_format().

Answer (score 0):

According to [DB2 doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html), you can use varchar_format() or to_char():

```
select varchar_format (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```